# PHP cURL not aible to show response

Tags: php, php-curl, snomed-ct

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

//$concept_id = $_POST['concept_id'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://browser.ihtsdotools.org/snowstorm/snomed-ct/browser/MAIN/2022-03-31/concepts/84114007");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));


$response = curl_exec($ch);
//echo curl_error($ch);
//echo '<p>';
//echo curl_errno($ch);
//echo '<p>';
$info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>\n$info<br>\n</pre>";

var_dump ($response);
?>
```

I am not able to retrieve the response of the SNOMED API. Works with my browser with the same URL.
I received no error message, just an empty response.

Tried to add these parameters without change :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Here the response:

```
array (
  'url' => 'https://browser.ihtsdotools.org/snowstorm/snomed-ct/browser/MAIN/2022-03-31/concepts/84114007',
  'content_type' => NULL,
  'http_code' => 423,
  'header_size' => 112,
  'request_size' => 123,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.61424600000000007,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.052975000000000001,
  'connect_time' => 0.15305099999999999,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.51591100000000001,
  'size_upload' => 0.0,
  'size_download' => 0.0,
  'speed_download' => 0.0,
  'speed_upload' => 0.0,
  'download_content_length' => 0.0,
  'upload_content_length' => 0.0,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.61422100000000002,
  'redirect_time' => 0.0,
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'primary_ip' => '3.225.65.37',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => 443,
  'local_ip' => '10.102.1.146',
  'local_port' => 41662,
)

string(0) ""
```

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: have you already changed the RETURNTRANSFER parameter to see what happens...? And yes, as @brombeer says, copy your code in your question, don't show screenshot

Comment: Yes I already tried every parameters combination :S

Comment: You have an http code 423. Have you looked for information on this return code...?

Comment: "HTTP/1.1 423 Server: nginx Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2023 11:51:49 GMT Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive" that's what I received if I set the CURLOPT_HEADER to true. Don't know if it help

Comment: It said it's a "Locked" code. Can't found more information about this. Is that the code that the API Server send back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we look for information on the 423 code returned, we see that sometimes pages are blocked because the client is not an Internet browser

So if we simulate an internet explorer with the "Agent" parameter, it works

Normally the code below should help you

```
// Determinate URL
$urlTest = "https://browser.ihtsdotools.org/snowstorm/snomed-ct/browser/MAIN/2022-03-31/concepts/84114007";

// Initialization Session CURL
$curlObject = @curl_init();

// Simulation of Agent
$config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

// Définition Options de la Session CURL
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_URL,$urlTest);


// Running Session CURL
$curlResponse = @curl_exec($curlObject);          


// If successful execution
if($curlResponse!=false)
{
    $dataList   = json_decode($curlResponse, true);      echo "<pre>"; print_r($dataList); echo "</pre>"; 
}
else echo "Error Connexion CURL - [".curl_errno($curlObject)."] ".curl_error($curlObject);
```

Comment: Thanks it work perfectly  it would be great if it would be added to the api documentation.